# Encoding within chunks results in missing characters despite UTF-8

Tags: r, encoding, r-markdown, knitr

I have an Rmd file encoded with UTF-8, but when I knit the file, R evaluated inline and chunk contents are missing some Czech characters. Everything is fine when I type the text outside of chunks. Reading the same text from a file, I can correctly produce the output inline, but not when using printing (`print` or `cat`) from within a chunk. I am completely confused about the situation, especially the `cat` behaviour.

I am on Windows. Checking encoding in console returns UTF-8. Locale set to English_United Kingdom.1252.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---
```{r}
txt <- "Čeština funguje"
print(Encoding(txt))
print(txt)      # prints incorrectly
```

Čeština funguje # prints correctly
`r txt`         # prints incorrectly

```{r}
cat(txt)        # prints incorrectly
```

```{r, results='asis'}
line <- readLines("line", encoding = "UTF-8")
print(Encoding(line))
print(line) # prints incorrectly
cat(line)   # prints incorrectly
```

`r line`    # prints correctly!
````

[image]

P.S. I know there has been a lot said about R and encoding on Windows, but despite my extensive searching I can't find a solution and don't fully understand this behaviour. I am guessing I need to set some locale, but my efforts so far have been in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before [R supports UTF-8 natively on Windows](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/07/30/windows/utf-8-build-of-r-and-cran-packages/index.html), usually you have to set the locale to the specific language if you want to use multi-byte characters from this language, e.g., you need to use the Czech locale instead of English if you want to properly `print()`/`cat()` Czech characters. The locale needs to be set before knitting happens, e.g., you may set it in your `~/.Rprofile`:

```r
Sys.setlocale(, 'Czech')
```

I have never used Czech before and am not sure if `'Czech'` is a proper value, but that's the idea (I have had success with other languages before).

Comment: Thank You so much! After you wrote this I was able to properly google it and fix it with code from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946483/czech-encoding-in-r). I have no idea why I didn't find that before :(